# Compilation failure in installing NTL library

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I'm trying to install NTL Library in Ubuntu and having problems

What I typed in the terminal is:

```
gunzip ntl-xxx.tar.gz
tar xf ntl-xxx.tar
cd ntl-xxx/src
./configure
```

After entering from the last line, the following error message appears.

```
Compilation failed
See compilerOutput.log for details
Goodbye! at DoConfig line 616.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I don't think we can help you without seeing compilerOutput.log's contents.

Comment: *** CompilerOutput.log ***
*** building GenConfigInfo ***
sh: 1: make: not found

Comment: @JHKwon You have installed the required build tools? `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: @JHKwon So you were simply missing 'make'? An easy fix then and welcome to askubuntu :)